# Would you create a View Model if it was the same as other pages?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, mvvm

Thanks to previous answers, I have now written View Models and really like this concept, however, there are points in the application where the View Model will be the exact same as the (Not sure on the term..) real model.

Now in this situation, I understand that a View Model is best as one day, I may change the application logic, and it makes the application more robust.

However, a situation I have now is where I have a multiple pages that are very closely linked to each other and all need the exact same Model. In this situation, would you use the same View Model or just create a separate identical one for each page?

Answer (score 2):

Are they exactly the same? In my opinion, if they are exactly the same you should reuse the ViewModel. Why create the same ViewModels twice whose functionality is basically the same. However, you should be careful that there are no service calls being in ViewModel constructor because, you may not need the exact same service calls for all views. In that case your calls are wasted even though you do not require it. In such a case make a public method in ViewModel like :

```
public void DoServiceCallsForViewA()
{
    ModelObj.FooA();    
}

public void DoServiceCallsForViewB()
{
    //your calls for view B 
    ModelObj.FooB();
}
```

Then in your viewA you can typecast the DataContext,

```
((YourViewModelName)DataContext).DoServiceCallsForViewA();
```

and in your viewB you can write :

```
((YourViewModelName)DataContext).DoServiceCallsForViewB();
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewModels should be simple data vehicles between views and controller actions (just a list of properties).  If they are simple lists of properties in your app you can use [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to make your eventual decision on this fine detail less important.

...not to evade the question, I would stick with one ViewModel definition while the views are demanding *exactly* the same data shuttle and be ready to create a new ViewModel when one of those views needs something ever so slightly different.

There is no need to duplicate except to make your view:action mappings obvious, but weighing the obvious mapping against violation of the DRY principle seems like a straightforward decision...

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, your Model instances should each have an associated ViewModel. That is to say, you should have a 1:1 relationship betweel Models and ViewModels. You are however free to bind multiple Views to the same ViewModel.

Say, for example, you have a Person object, and a PersonViewModel, and then two different Views relating to that Person, say a PersonEditView and a PersonDetailsView. You should put all the neccessary properties for both PersonEditView and PersonDetailsView into PersonViewModel. Then use a `DataTemplateSelector` to choose which View should be displayed for the ViewModel at which times.

The each ViewModel instance should be a representative for a single Model instance, and it should be the only representative for that Model instance.